# Derivative of a scalar function with respect to a matrix

Tags: matrices, derivatives

What is the derivative of $a=y^{T}Ax$ with respect to a matrix, B, where y(B) and x(B) are vectors and A is a matrix that is not a function of B?

I have found an expression for taking the derivative to a vector, z, instead of B, which is given as:

$\frac{\partial a}{\partial z}=y^TA\frac{\partial x}{\partial z}+x^{T}A^T\frac{\partial y}{\partial z}$

But am not sure how to take this a step further and take the derivative with respect to B.

I am not well versed in matrix differentiation, and have not seen an answer to this specific question.

Thank you!